# ActiViz .NET LeftButtonReleaseEvent: Where did i click

Tags: c#, .net, events, mouseevent, vtk

I'm working with ActiViz .NET (VTK) and have a small problem.

When I register a event (for ex. the LeftButtonReleaseEvt), I can't find out where on the RenderWindowControl I clicked.  The event is called.

```
        ...       
        rwcVtk.RenderWindow.GetInteractor().LeftButtonPressEvt += new vtkObject.vtkObjectEventHandler(RenderWindow_LeftButtonReleaseEvt);            
    }

    void RenderWindow_LeftButtonReleaseEvt(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Where did i click?
    }
```

Can somebody help me?
There isn't much documentation on that out there I think.

Comment: The vtkObjectEventArgs doesn't contain any information on your click? I would expect it to work like MouseEventArgs with more information considering they rolled their own.

Comment: thought so too. e.CallData is a IntPtr. What can i do with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try out this, but maybe your are looking for this property:

```
this.Interactor.GetLastEventPosition();
```

To see this working go to your Activiz Examples folder "Examples\VolumeRendering\CS" and see that example.

Comment: Its `RenderWindowControl.` `RenderWindow.GetInteractor().` `GetLastEventPosition()`